# Pandas Heatmap: could not convert string to float

Tags: pandas

please tell me, I'm trying to do a training competition on Kaggle, I want to build a heatmap based on a dataset, as one author of the guide did, but I complain that there are categorical signs, but the chatgpt says that pandas automatically ignores categorical signs and builds a heatmap based on numerical ones, and the author of the guide himself did not do any preliminary processing

```
hp_train.corr()
```

Error:

```
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 hp_train.corr()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:10054, in DataFrame.corr(self, method, min_periods, numeric_only)
  10052 cols = data.columns
  10053 idx = cols.copy()
> 10054 mat = data.to_numpy(dtype=float, na_value=np.nan, copy=False)
  10056 if method == "pearson":
  10057     correl = libalgos.nancorr(mat, minp=min_periods)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:1838, in DataFrame.to_numpy(self, dtype, copy, na_value)
   1836 if dtype is not None:
   1837     dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
-> 1838 result = self._mgr.as_array(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, na_value=na_value)
   1839 if result.dtype is not dtype:
   1840     result = np.array(result, dtype=dtype, copy=False)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py:1732, in BlockManager.as_array(self, dtype, copy, na_value)
   1730         arr.flags.writeable = False
   1731 else:
-> 1732     arr = self._interleave(dtype=dtype, na_value=na_value)
   1733     # The underlying data was copied within _interleave, so no need
   1734     # to further copy if copy=True or setting na_value
   1736 if na_value is not lib.no_default:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py:1794, in BlockManager._interleave(self, dtype, na_value)
   1792     else:
   1793         arr = blk.get_values(dtype)
-> 1794     result[rl.indexer] = arr
   1795     itemmask[rl.indexer] = 1
   1797 if not itemmask.all():

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RL'
```

[https://www.kaggle.com/code/pmarcelino/comprehensive-data-exploration-with-python/notebook#2.-First-things-first:-analysing-'SalePrice'](https://www.kaggle.com/code/pmarcelino/comprehensive-data-exploration-with-python/notebook#2.-First-things-first:-analysing-%27SalePrice%27)

Comment: Hi @lemintare welcome to the site. I think you might have modified the dataframe somehow, as "RL" is not in the original dataset for the kaggle competition. When I load the data from a .csv into a dataframe, and take the correlation matrix and create a heatmap, everything works fine.

Comment: idk bro im tilted nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

You can check column dtypes using `hp_train.dtypes`. Subset the dataframe for only the desired columns before calling `corr`.

For example if you only want `float64` cols

```py
dtype_df = hp_train.dtypes
float_cols = dtype_df.iloc[(dtype_df=='float64').values].index
hp_train[float_cols].corr()
```

Comment: ye, but why didn't the author of the guide do this

Answer (score 0):

We have got 'tips' dataframe with 6 columns

```
total_bill  tip sex smoker  day time    size
```

Here total_bill,tip are of float ; size is int;rest are String

Suppose you have string column,float column,int column in your dataframe.For tips.corr() we can use only float column but int columns too (if first we convert them from int to float)

Here we can use total_bill(float),tip(float),size(but first we need to convert size from int to float) for making correlational matrix

First convert size from int to float

**convert_dict = {'size': float }**

**tips=tips.astype(convert_dict)**

If you have any other int columns other than size, than add that column name as key and float as value in above dictionary convert_dict

Now all required columns are in float ,now use below code

**dtype_df = tips.dtypes**

**float_cols = dtype_df.iloc[(dtype_df=='float64').values].index**

**tips_tips=tips[float_cols].corr()**

**sns.heatmap(tips_tips)**

using this 6 Bold line as code you can convert any dataframe (float columns+int (converted to float) columns) into correlational matrix to form heatmap

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same error while trying to create a heatmap. Following code solved my problem.

```
    hp_train.corr(numeric_only=True)
```